# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout after 60000 ms when using camel-ahc

Tags: http, apache-camel

I have a simple web service, ws1, that just has a setBody to "hello world" which is exposed by netty. I want to call this web service asynchronously  with the help of camel-ahc.

for doing that, I have a main camel context that call the ws1 every 6 seconds, but after calling ws1 in another thread, the control of the program is not returning to the main camel context thread and it seems camel-ahc component is not working and after 60 seconds a request timeout exception is happening.
in my pom i have added:
camel-ahc
camel-reactive-streams

```
<camelContext trace="true" id="mainCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >
       <route id="ahc-route-first-api">
        <from uri="timer://webinar?period=6000"/> 
              <log message="this is body: ${body}"/>
        <to uri="ahc:http://192.168.*.*:9999/ws1"/>
              <log message="this is body after call: ${body}"/>
       </route>

</camelContext>
```

when install bundle in Fuse:

> 10:35:18.914 INFO [Camel (mainCamelContext) thread #316 -
> timer://webinar] this is body:  10:35:18.914 INFO [Camel
> (mainCamelContext) thread #316 - timer://webinar]
> ID-localhost-localdomain-1552973873885-38-116 >>>
> (ahc-route-first-api) log[this is body: ${body}] -->
> ahc://http://192.168.*.*:9999/api?throwExceptionOnFailure=false
> <<< Pattern:InOnly,
> Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-localhost-localdomain-1552973873885-38-116,
> firedTime=Sat Apr 06 10:35:18 IRDT 2019}, BodyType:null, Body:[Body is
> null] 10:35:19.202 WARN [AsyncHttpClient-timer-87-1] Error processing
> exchange. Exchange[ID-localhost-localdomain-1552973873885-38-114].
> Caused by: [java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException - Request timeout to
> 192.168.*.*/192.168.*.*:9999 after 60000 ms] java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to
> 192.168.*.*/192.168.*.*:9999 after 60000 ms   at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
> [1990:wrap_file__home_ossl_.m2_repository_org_asynchttpclient_async-http-client_2.4.3_async-http-client-2.4.3.jar_Export-Package_org.asynchttpclient._*version_2.4.3:0.0.0]
> at
> org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:50)
> [1990:wrap_file__home_ossl*.m2_repository_org_asynchttpclient_async-http-client_2.4.3_async-http-client-2.4.3.jar_Export-Package_org.asynchttpclient.__version_2.4.3:0.0.0]
> at
> io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:663)
> [654:io.netty.common:4.1.16.Final-redhat-2]   at
> io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:738)
> [654:io.netty.common:4.1.16.Final-redhat-2]   at
> io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:466)
> [654:io.netty.common:4.1.16.Final-redhat-2]   at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
> [654:io.netty.common:4.1.16.Final-redhat-2]   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?] 10:35:19.203 ERROR
> [AsyncHttpClient-timer-87-1] Failed delivery for (MessageId:
> ID-localhost-localdomain-1552973873885-38-117 on ExchangeId:
> ID-localhost-localdomain-1552973873885-38-114). Exhausted after
> delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
> Request timeout to 192.168.*.*/192.168.*.*:9999 after 60000 ms